# Scala pattern match on type parameter

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, type-erasure, type-parameter, generic-type-argument

I want to get rid of type erasure warnings of this sample code:

```
val a: Seq[Any] = Seq(1)
a match {
  case b: Seq[Int] => b.map(c => println(2 * c) )
  case _ => println("Not matched")
}
```

It compiles and works ok, but with a warning:

> Warning:(31, 13) non-variable type argument Int in type pattern
>   Seq[Int] (the underlying of Seq[Int]) is unchecked since it is
>   eliminated by erasure
>       case b: Seq[Int] => b.map(c => println(2 * c) )
>               ^

Do you have any simple solution for avoiding the erasure in this case?

What have I tried so far (accorting to [this](http://queirozf.com/entries/scala-goodies-pattern-matching-with-typed-lists-or-working-around-scala-s-type-erasure)):

```
val a: Seq[Any] = Seq(1)
a match {
  case b@Seq(_:Int) => b.map(c => println(2 * c) )
  case _ => println("Not matched")
}
```

But it won't compile because c is now of type Any.

I believe there are several solution to this problem. I will accept the simplest one.

Comment: Note that your approach breaks parametricity - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7810909/talks/parametricity/4985cb8e6d8d9a24e32d98204526c8e3b9319e33/parametricity.pdf.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the this is a simplest solution but I think it's better to match over type with `TypeTag`s

```
def matchOnList[A: TypeTag](l: List[A]) = typeOf[A] match {
    case t if t =:= typeOf[Int] =>
      l.asInstanceOf[List[Int]].foreach(c => println(2 * c))
    case _ => println("Not matched")
  }

val a = List(1)

matchOnList(a)
```

Comment: Yeah, this one I have already seen somewhere, I don't like the `asInstanceOf` usage.

Comment: @mirelon me too :) but I don't have an idea how to avoid casting.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
  case b: Seq[Int @unchecked] => b.map(c => println(2 * c))
```

will get rid of the warning. But it won't solve underlying problem of erasure. `Seq("1")` will match this case.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I ended up doing something like this (didn't find anything prettier):

```
val a: Seq[Any] = Seq(1)
a match {
  case b: Seq[_] => b.map(c =>
    c match {
      case s: Int => print(2 * s)
      case _ => print("Not matched")
    })
  case _ => print("Not matched")
}
```